# Regex and StringTokenizer Syntax Error

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

I'm new to regular expressions and `StringTokenizer`, and I'm getting a syntax error whenever I put this regex in `matches`:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");

    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String function = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();

        if (function.matches(\\s*(unsigned int|float|int|char|void|double)(\\s)+[a-zA-Z_](\\w)*(\\s)*\\((\\s)*((((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*,(\\s)*)*((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*))|(\\s)*|(void)(\\s)*)\\)(\\s)*\\;)) {
            System.out.println("VALID - ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a copy and paste error, but it could be that you're missing the quotes around your regex to make it a `String`.

Comment: FYI from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Must be lack of sleep, but thanks Brian! 
It works now -.-

The tutorial I was reading online didn't place quotations and I don't know why it didn't occur to me that t needed some. Cheers!

Comment: @Brian You should post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enclose your string withing quotes **" "**, And note that when using the operator "or" (|) for two consecutive words, we should use them in parenthesis `((unsigned int) | float)`

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");

while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    String function = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();

    if (function.matches("\\s*((unsigned int)|float|int|char|void|double)(\\s)+[a-zA-Z_](\\w)*(\\s)*\\((\\s)*((((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*,(\\s)*)*((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*))|(\\s)*|(void)(\\s)*)\\)(\\s)*\\;")) {
        System.out.println("VALID - ");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a copy and paste error, but it could be that you're missing the quotes around your regex to make it a `String`. For example:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");

    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String function = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();

        if (function.matches("\\s*(unsigned int|float|int|char|void|double)(\\s)+[a-zA-Z_](\\w)*(\\s)*\\((\\s)*((((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*,(\\s)*)*((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*))|(\\s)*|(void)(\\s)*)\\)(\\s)*\\;")) {
            System.out.println("VALID - ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`matches` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) takes `String` as method argument... So, enclose your regex withing quoutes **" "** 
like this:

```
function.matches("\\s*(unsigned int|float|int|char|void|double)(\\s)+[a-zA-Z_](\\w)*(\\s)*\\((\\s)*((((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*,(\\s)*)*((unsigned int|float|int|char|double)(\\s)*))|(\\s)*|(void)(\\s)*)\\)(\\s)*\\;)")
```